# Field with type 'Term Reference' (only if I use View as data source) display N/A as first value

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a field with type 'Term reference' and widget 'Check boxes/radio buttons'.
As a first value I have a N/A and I've no clue why it appears there.

Term reference works fine if I do not use View.
It's not required to be filled.

[image]

Is it possible to remove it in proper way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A very late answer, but hopefully it will still help you.
I think if you change the term reference field, you have an option if it is optional or mandatory the field. When you choose mandatory, it should be removed that option.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a list field mandatory, the N/A option automatically goes away

**OR**

```
<?php
unset($form['field_name']['und']['#options']['_none']);
?>
```